# WORDPRESS - How to implement jquery tabs that loads content dynamically when tab is clicked

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm trying to create a tabs in wordpress that loads content dynamically when tab is clicked.
However, I'm having trouble calling the content.php files which I have created to list posts of a specific category.

I know I  have to put this in the file in order to load all the wordpress stuff
`require('./wp-blog-header.php');`

This is the tabs block.  loading "index.php" is fine because is under the "home" directory.
Loading "content.php" is the problem which is located under the "themes/default" directory.

Your help is appreciated.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Preloaded</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="content.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>`
```

Comment: Did you....make some files, throw them in your wp-content folder, and now are wanting to call them dynamically? I mean...in reality, we would use ajax, and a click handler to determine what content to load. We would use the functions.php file to handle the ajax request, query the data we want, then spit it back out to be displayed in the success function of our ajax call. We would test for the presence of content in a tab, so we don't needlessly query the db over and over.

Comment: is there a sample code that I can take a look?  thanks